# Angularjs grid selectedItems always returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

Any reason the angularjs grid in my sample won't show the selectedItems properly? That is, any time I try to reference the selectedItems I get "undefined." I've tried in Chrome and IE with the same result.

I've made a plnkr that is the "basic" example on the angular grid page with a bit of extra javascript to try and show the selected items.
The plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/wPnMGQOzKSOTdeaAjoB8?p=preview

The relevent code:

```
 $scope.gridOptions = { 
      data: 'myData',
      selectedItems: $scope.mySelections,
      afterSelectionChange: function (row, event) {
                    if (row.selected) {
                      alert('Items selected ' + $scope.mySelections);
                      alert('Items selected ' + $scope.gridOptions.selectedItems)
                    }
                }

    };
```

I get "undefined" when trying to evaluate the selected items, either with $scope.mySelections or via the grid directly. I've put a "debugger;" line in "if" and checked the values - there doesn't appear to be a selectedItems property on the grid?

(edit: removed the ** from the code block. Forgot you can't boldface code here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to initialize your `$scope.mySelections` property. Because of this, every time you'd print its value, you would get `undefined`.

Check a fixed [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/rN4l489fBxHPMmK1Vhyc?p=preview).

Of course, it alerts a [Object object] for each, but this is a matter of how you want to print your objects.

If you want to alert your objects in a more sensible way, you could do something like [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qm9T1ZiM8aN8wWqvUpHV?p=preview).

Comment: Ah dern - missed that initializer every time. I assumed the selectedItems would have set it to a valid array automatically. Thanks for the fix! And also - seems your first plnkr had some leftover test code - you had left in setting of an index and manually doing a .push() of the selected row. Had me confused for a minute thinking I'd have to manually push/splice the selectedItems :) But all good!

Comment: Yeah, you are right, some trash code was left behind. It's fixed now.